# Static code tester / analyser for Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, static-analysis

Is there any static code tester available for Angular.js?

For Ruby, I have `Rubocop`. Similar to this, is there any command line tool available to test the best practices for angularjs coding?

Answer (score 2):

#### [Angular-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-lint)

I would look into Angular JS Linter, it should be what you're looking for. It's basically a set of ESLint rules to lint source code that uses the angular framework. Note that this software is still in development. It's licensed under the [MIT License](https://github.com/Nate-Wilkins/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT)

To install, simply type this is a command line to do so,

```
$ npm install angular-lint
$ N/A bower install angular-lint
```

Comment: @Sayuj did you try this? Did it help you?